# Storing ASCII characters in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, numbers, ascii

I am trying to make a random generator using ASCII characters and due to my minimal knowledge, I am having difficulty trying to identify the best way to go about making this random generator.

Currently, I have managed to make a simple array which currently holds 6 values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

    int main()
{
    int i;

    int  array[255] = {1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6 };

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", array[i]); /* Prints out all values declared in the array*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> output: 123456

What I am currently stuck on now is trying to find out how to replace the numbers with ASCII characters. If anyone could help me figure this out, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial code is already pretty accurate.

Your only mistake is: `printf("%d", array[i]);`

The **%d** specifier will output an **signed decimal integer**, to output a character use the **%c** specifier. 
You can view all the documentation (including specifiers) for `printf` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

I also took the liberty of replacing the elements in the array with integers that result in alphanumeric output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int array[255] = { 65, 66, 67 , 68, 69, 70 };

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", array[i]); // Outputs: ABCDEF
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Your next steps are to just randomise length and the elements of the array! Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your input, the explanation you've provided was very helpful. The next stage of this mini project is tackling the randomiser and then I would like to add a function that allows the user to select how long the output should be. Fingers crossed I can do it.

Comment: Make sure the integers you generate are within the range of visible characters! [Here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) is a table which provides the valid integers. Alphanumeric characters would be: 65 to 90, 97 to 122 and 48 to 57.

Comment: @hymcode If this resolved your issue can you mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use character literals in the array elements, and print them with `%c` format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    int  array[255] = {'1', '2', '3' , '4', '5', '6' };

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", array[i]); /* Prints out all values declared in the array*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could also change the declaration of the array to `char array[255]`, since it only holds characters. For the purposes of `printf()` it doesn't matter, because `char` variables are automatically converted to `int` when calling a variadic function like `printf` (but I wouldn't be surprised if compilers print a warning about it, since it's unusual).

Comment: Would that need more explanation as to why you pass `int` to `%c` format specifier?

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: @Barmar I cannot believe it was that simple. Thank you very much, that seems to have done the trick with displaying them. The only issue I am having now is that some of the outputs just display as a . Any idea how I would go about solving that, or is this a limitation in cmd not being about display certain characters?

Comment: It's only useful for printing printing characters, not control characters. Control characters perform their operation, e.g. `\n` will go to the next line.

Comment: What are you expecting instead?

Comment: @Barmar sorry my earlier comment didn't output correctly. So I changed the array values with a random selection from the ASCII table. One displays the correct character, but the rest are just squares []. I took a screenshot which hopefully will help. https://ibb.co/iESn6z

Comment: Printing ASCII characters have codes from 32 to 126.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the computer does not know anything about the characters - from its poit of view everything is just the number.

`char` type is just the integer value of the size (in bits) CHAR_BITS. In most systems it is 8 bits. Depending on your implementation and compile options `char` can be signed or unsigned.

Lets consider the signed version. On 32 bit system:

`int` type is usually 32 bits wide,

`short` is usually 16 bits wide

`char` is usually 8 bits wide

so it can be called supershort :)

`typedef char supershort;`

So there is no difference between them except the range of the values those types can accommodate.

Beginners are often confused by the char constants: `'a'`, `'b'` .... etc and it makes them think that `char` is something special , but it is only for the humans convenience - it is much more difficult to remember the whole ASCII table.

You can use them with any other number types:
`long x = 'a'`;
or even `double y = '#'`

Assuming : you can use `char` type as any other integer type.